# I am able to transfer files over ssh from Jenkins but unable to see those files in my remote directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, ssh, scp

I have Jenkins pipeline, where I am cloning the source code into my Jenkins workspace & want to copy these files into my Dev Server's test directory. So I have use publish over ssh plugin, Done all the required configuration. I am able to transfer files using it.

Here is the Jenkins console output:

[image: Here is the Jenkins console output]

But I cannot see any files present into that directory on dev-server i.e. test

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

have you given your destination path which is your Dev server's test directory? (Not just Dev server)
If you have just given the Dev server then, it will be in the root of your dev server's file system.